# Remove index.php from URL after query params without using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, apache2, httpd.conf

I want to remove `index.php` from my URL after query params.

This is my URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1/user/report?user=USERNAME
```

I have removed query params and convert it into pretty URL using:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !user=
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/(.*)$ $2?user=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ ?user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Now, my URL looks like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1/user/report/USERNAME
```

So all the requests to this URL will point to the entry script of my project i.e. `web/index.php`.

When I use below routes to get data, it works:

```
http://127.0.0.1/user/report/Default/index.php/api/registration/user-registrations/
```

But when I remove `index.php` from URL and access it like below, it throws 404:

```
http://127.0.0.1/user/report/Default/api/registration/user-registrations/
```

Apache config file:

```
Alias /user/report /path/to/project/web/
<Directory /path/to/project/web/>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all Granted
    RewriteOptions AllowNoSlash

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /user/report/
    RewriteOptions AllowNoSlash

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^[^.]+[^\/]$ $0\/ [R]

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !user=
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/(.*)$ $2?user=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ ?user=$1 [L,QSA]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(bmp|css|cur|gif|ico|jpe?g|m?js|png|svgz?|webp|webmanifest|pdf)$ $1.$3 [L]
</Directory>
```

I am using Symfony for routing all my routes.

Comment: Hi Akshay, Can you share minimal repo which can reproduce this issue? I would like to play locally with a project having a similar issue. If you have any open source project which can reproduce the issue you can share that too

Comment: Have you changed anything in any apache conf file? I assume you have only modified .htaccess file present in your project, right?

Comment: No, I don't have any .htaccess in the project. I am redirecting using apace site conf.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Apache 2.4, and do not want to to use `.htaccess` files (e.g. for performance reasons), the solution is simply to use a oneliner: [`FallBackResource`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource).

You would only need this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.tld
    ServerAlias www.domain.tld

    DocumentRoot /var/www/project/public
    DirectoryIndex /index.php

    <Directory /var/www/project/public>
        AllowOverride None
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All

        FallbackResource /index.php
    </Directory>

    # optionally disable the fallback resource for the asset directories
    # which will allow Apache to return a 404 error when files are
    # not found instead of passing the request to Symfony
    <Directory /var/www/project/public/bundles>
        FallbackResource disabled
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This is even shown in [Symfony's documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#apache-with-mod-php-php-cgi).

Comment: 403 is "not authorized". Do you have any kind of security in your symfony site?

Comment: No. I have given the appropriate permissions also.

Comment: Actually I am using httpd.

Comment: What do you mean "httpd"? Httpd is Apache, nothing more. You should find out your apache version (run `httpd -v`), and add the rest of your configuration.

Comment: It's Apache/2.4.41.

Comment: Ok, now add your complete configuration to your question, so we can help you. :)

Comment: Update question with apache config.